# Add to Command Action From Parent Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, command

I have a custom control that is a textbox with an embedded button for clearing the textbox. The button is wired to the `ApplicationCommands.Delete` command with the target as the textbox. This works exactly as expected.

My problem is that I have another control that uses this custom textbox, and needs to know when the `ApplicationCommands.Delete` is executed so that it can run its own actions on top of the default actions. I have tried to add to the `CommandBindings`, but that does not work. Is there a way to receive notification of a command at a parent level `UIElement`?

TextBox Custom Control XAML

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" Executed="ClearTextBoxExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
...
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilteredTextBox}"
```

Code behind:

```
private void ClearTextBoxExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!(e.OriginalSource is TextBox)) return;
  var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
  textBox.Clear();
  if (TextCleared != null)
    TextCleared(sender, null);
}
```

Xaml wrapping the textbox due to assembly Resource Uri constraints

```
<UserControl x:Class="CopyOfEnhancedTextboxForLocalInheritance" Name="MainWrapper">
<textBoxes:EnhancedTextBox x:Name="EnhancedTextBox"...
```

HotKeySelectorTextBox:

```
public class HotKeySelectorBox : CustomTextBox
{
  void SetupCommands()
  {
    var deleteCommand = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Delete,
                                         (sender, args) => 
                                           DeleteSelection());
    deleteCommand.CanExecute +=
    (sender, args) =>
      {
        args.Handled = true;
        args.CanExecute = !(Text == String.Empty || Text == "none");
      };
    EnhancedTextBox.CommandBindings.Add(deleteCommand);
    CommandBindings.Add(deleteCommand);
  }
}
```

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: Right now, as a temporary solution, I am just publishing an event after the initial command fires